# How do I list out all the different labels/strings in a certain column?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, numpy

I would like to list out each name of label/string that exists in a specific columns.  such labels will appear multiple times in the column (eg. Fleet, Travel etc) : eg

```
Column1         Column2
Facility        Machine
Fleet           Other
Travel          Leased Vehicles
......          .......
```

How do I write the code to extract the labels in numpy array ?

Thank you.

Desired output 
eg.  feature_labels = np.array(['Column1_Facility', 'Column1_Fleet', 'Column2_Machine', etc

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure I fully understand the question, but here is my attempt:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['Facility', 'Fleet', 'Travel'], 'Column2': ['Machine', 'Other', 'Leased Vehicles']})
df

#Outputs:
    Column1 Column2
0   Facility    Machine
1   Fleet   Other
2   Travel  Leased Vehicles
```

Then iterate over the columns to append the column name to the feature name as you want:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: f'{col}_{x}')
```

The above would give you:

```
             Column1    Column2
0   Column1_Facility    Column2_Machine
1   Column1_Fleet       Column2_Other
2   Column1_Travel      Column2_Leased Vehicles
```

And now you can simply extract the values of each column:

```
df.Column1.values
```

Result:

> array(['Column1_Facility', 'Column1_Fleet', 'Column1_Travel'],
>         dtype=object)

**EDIT:**

If you want to list only the unique values in a column:

```
             Column1    Column2
0   Column1_Facility    Column2_Machine
1   Column1_Fleet       Column2_Other
2   Column1_Travel      Column2_Leased Vehicles
3   Column1_Facility    Column2_Machine
```

You'll need to use:

```
df.Column1.unique()
```

Result:

> array(['Column1_Facility', 'Column1_Fleet', 'Column1_Travel'],
>         dtype=object)

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the quick response.  i tested out your suggestion and got the below response :

array(['Category_Facility', 'Category_Fleet', 'Category_Fleet', ...,
       'Category_Travel and Entertainment', 'Category_Other',
       'Category_nan'], dtype=object)

Comment: Thank you ! if the same name labels (eg. Fleet, Others etc)  in a column appears multiple times (multiple rows) but i want it to be listed in the array only once, how would the new code look ?  for example, if there are label names in one column (associated with hundred thousands of rows) and i only need to know what are the different names of each label that exists in that one specific column only.  Hopefully I am able to explain this clearly.  

Thank you again.

Comment: You'll need to use `df.Column1.unique()` instead of `.values`

Comment: Hi again, hope you can help again here.  seems that each time i ran the same cell, the column word (eg "category") is concatenated throughout :  

for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: f'{col}_{x}')
df.Category.unique()

results after 4 runs...:it kept building on the last run. 

array(['Category_Category_Category_Category_Category_Facility',
       'Category_Category_Category_Category_Category_Fleet'.....etc

I just want to show 1 time of the column header (eg. "Category").  Thank you

Comment: you shouldn't run the for loop multiple times. Every time it's ran, it will append the column name to the values in each column. You either can get it into a function and call only once, or just call at the very beginning of your notebook and never call again.

Comment: got it.  thanks !   thought there was a way to get around but running it once is fine.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` has the `char` module for quasi-vectorized string operations. You could for example use `np.char.add`:

```
import functools as ft

data
# array([['Column1', 'Column2'],
#        ['Facility', 'Machine'],
#        ['Fleet', 'Other'],
#        ['Travel', 'Leased Vehicles'],
#        ['......', '.......']], dtype='<U15')

ft.reduce(np.char.add, (data[:1], '_', data[1:]))
# array([['Column1_Facility', 'Column2_Machine'],
#        ['Column1_Fleet', 'Column2_Other'],
#        ['Column1_Travel', 'Column2_Leased Vehicles'],
#        ['Column1_......', 'Column2_.......']], dtype='<U31')
```

Comment: Thank you.  helps with another question I had in mind :)